# How to resolve this ERROR in react-native?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

```
import React,{ useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import {AppLoading} from 'expo-app-loading';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import Home from './screens/home';


const fetchFont = () =>{
  Font.loadAsync({
    'glory':require('./assets/fonts/Glory.ttf')
  });
};

export default function App() {

  const [fontloaded,setfontloaded] = useState(false)  

  if(!fontloaded){
    return (
      <AppLoading startAsync={fetchFont} onFinish={()=>{setfontloaded(true)}} />
    )
  }else{
    return (
      <Home />
    );
  }

  
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

**And the error is:**

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot
to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check your code at App.js:22.
in App (created by ExpoRoot)
in ExpoRoot (at renderApplication.js:45)
in RCTView (at View.js:34)
in View (at AppContainer.js:106)
in RCTView (at View.js:34)
in View (at AppContainer.js:132)
in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)

I face this error when I use .

Comment: I face this error when I use <AppLoading />

Answer (score 0):

Import the `AppLoading` component properly.

It should be

```js
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';
```

the imports with `{}` are for named exports. For defaults exports, you can simply import it with any name.

Read https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/app-loading/ for more information.